# Chrome extension: download text file in the latest version of Chrome

Tags: text, google-chrome-extension, download, click

I'm a newbie of Chrome extension development. I'm working on a project which needs to generate a text file for user to download. With the help of experts in the Internet, I'm using a function like this:

```
function saveText(filename, text) {
    var tempElem = document.createElement('a');
    tempElem.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    tempElem.setAttribute('download', filename);
    tempElem.click();
}
```

This function works perfect before. But when the Chrome was updated today, it no longer works - no prompt in the background console, the scripts work fine before and after this function. I've tried all the method, but cannot find why.

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/821219. Try the workaround in comment 2 there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution there works. You saved me a day! Thank you.